# How to print a pointer address without printf

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

I'm doing an exercise in which I need to print the memory (address) of a pointer. It would be easy to do it with `printf("%p", ..)` but I'm not allowed to use it.

Do you know how I can get the address without using `printf()`?
The only function I can use is 'write'.

Here is the statement of my exercise :

*Write a function that takes `(const void *addr, size_t size)`, and displays the
memory as in the example.
Your function must be declared as follows:*

```
void print_memory(const void *addr, size_t size);
```

---

```
$ cat main.c

void  print_memory(const void *addr, size_t size);

int   main(void)
{    
      int tab[10] = {0, 23, 150, 255,
                     12, 16,  21, 42};

      print_memory(tab, sizeof(tab));
      return (0);
}

$ gcc -Wall -Wall -Werror main.c print_memory.c && ./a.out | cat -e
0000 0000 1700 0000 9600 0000 ff00 0000 ................$
0c00 0000 1000 0000 1500 0000 2a00 0000 ............*...$
0000 0000 0000 0000                     ........$
```

Comment: "I need to print the memory of a pointer" Hmmm, that's a bit unclear to me. Do you want to print the value of the pointer or the memory that it points to?

Comment: I want to print the memory that is points to, like that "0000 0000 1700 0000 9600 0000 ff00 0000" for example

Comment: Are you saying that you can't use printf() at all or that you can't use %p?

Comment: Can't use printf at all, still can use write tho

Comment: How could you possibly print formatted output without `printf()`?

Comment: That's my question :)

Comment: @machine_1: The code that implements `printf` does exactly that, so it's certainly possible.

Comment: @machine_1 I certainly skirted the letter of the law here by using `sprintf()` in the answer posted, but outputting formatted text without `printf()` is a simple task.  Think about how we outputted formatted output before `printf()` existed.  Or think about how you would implement `printf()` if you were implementing a C library while designing an operating system, for example.  It's pretty trivial, just inconvenient

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. `printf("%p", ...)` prints the address (pointer value). But in your comment, "0000 0000 1700 0000 9600 0000 ff00 0000" looks more like the contents of 16 byte of memory at that address; that's 128 bits, which is *probably* bigger than a pointer value.

Comment: @KeithThompson I certainly agree, but then you would be using the same code of `printf()`, wouldn't you?

Comment: @KeithThompson Indeed, I actually have to print several adresses from an array,

Comment: @GautierLemaire: It's still not clear what you want to do. What are "addresses from an array"? Do you mean you have an array of pointers, and you want to print the value of each element of the array? Probably the clearest way to ask your question would be to show code that does what you want using `printf("%p", ...)` and ask how to do the same thing without using `printf`. (And since this appears to be a homework problem, I'd be very hesitant to provide a complete answer, though I would be willing to send code to your instructor with your name attached.)

Comment: This isn’t actually implementable with `printf("%p", ...)`, and least not easily or directly. The *address*, or the value of the pointer, is where in memory something lives; this doesn’t care about that and prints the memory *pointed to* by the pointer, or which is *at* that address (assuming little-endian).

Comment: The whole thing about `"%p"` turns out to have been a red herring (unintentionally, I'm sure). The assignment isn't to print address values. It's to print the contents of memory (in hexadecimal). `"%p"` is used to print pointer values, not the contents of the memory a pointer points to.

Comment: @KeithThompson Actually I don't have a teacher I'm learning alone ont internet and I found this exercice online. I think I misunderstood the exercice, it has nothing to do with "%p" thank you very much, it's a bit clearer for me now :) Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_memory(const void *addr, size_t size)
{
    size_t printed = 0;
    size_t i;
    const unsigned char* pc = addr;
    for (i=0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        int  g;
        g = (*(pc+i) >> 4) & 0xf;
        g += g >= 10 ? 'a'-10 : '0';
        putchar(g);
        printed++;

        g = *(pc+i) & 0xf;
        g += g >= 10 ? 'a'-10 : '0';
        putchar(g);
        printed++;
        if (printed % 32 == 0) putchar('\n');
        else if (printed % 4 == 0) putchar(' ');
    }
}

int main(void) {
int tab[10] = {0, 23, 150, 255, 12, 16, 21, 42};

print_memory(tab, sizeof(tab)); return (0);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
0000 0000 1700 0000 9600 0000 ff00 0000 
0c00 0000 1000 0000 1500 0000 2a00 0000 
0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Comment: I'm doing the same exercise as the op, where I actually have to print the address and dump the memory. the twist is I am limited to 25 lines per function and can't use ternaries. I tried to convert your code but it printed as \x1f\xefO\x1f\x7fO\xaf\x7f\xdf\xaf\x0f\xdf?6of can you help me out?

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT:** I provided this answer before the OP clarified they actually wanted to **dump** memory contents (before clarifying it they asked for code to act like `printf("%p", mem_ptr)`.

This code should spell out each digit (in hex):

```
#include <stdint.h>

/* you must provide this function somewhere */
extern void write_char(char);

char hex_digit(int v) {
    if (v >= 0 && v < 10)
        return '0' + v;
    else
        return 'a' + v - 10; // <-- Here
}

void print_address_hex(void* p0) {
    int i;
    uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t)p0;

    write_char('0'); write_char('x');
    for(i = (sizeof(p) << 3) - 4; i>=0; i -= 4) {
        write_char(hex_digit((p >> i) & 0xf));
    }
}
```

Here, `print_address_hex` is a basic algorithm for printing digits one at a time ([like this one](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Recursion/pythondsConvertinganIntegertoaStringinAnyBase.html)). [to simplify things I didn't care about leading zeros]

The core of the algorithm are the operators `>>` (acts like binary integer division) and `&` (acts like binary remainder). [notice that those operators will only work for bases 2, 4, 8, 16, 2^n in general].

I used `uintptr_t` to make it portable. This type - declared in `<stdint.h>` - refers to an integral type capable of holding a pointer (architecture independent). We need an integral type so that we can use arithmetic operators (besides `+` and `-`, the only valid operators for pointer arithmetic).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to print the memory, you have to transform each byte from addr in hexadecimal and print it, the second part with dots and asterisk is transform the value of each byte in char, if it isn't printable it will print dot.

```
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    print_ascii(const char *addr, int i)
{
    int j;
    int len;

    j = 0;
    if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0)
        len = 16;
    else
        len = (i + 1) % 16;
    while (j < 16 - len)
    {
        ft_putchar(' ');
        ft_putchar(' ');
        if (j % 2)
            ft_putchar(' ');
        j++;
    }
    if ((16 - len) % 2)
        ft_putchar(' ');
    j = 0;
    while (j < len)
    {
        if (*(addr + i / 16 * 16 + j) >= 32 && *(addr + i / 16 * 16 + j) <= 126)
            ft_putchar(*(addr + i / 16 * 16 + j));
        else
            ft_putchar('.');
        j++;
    }
    ft_putchar('\n');
}

void    print_hex(unsigned char value, int index)
{
    if (index < 2)
    {
        print_hex(value / 16, index + 1);
        if (value % 16 >= 10)
            ft_putchar('a' + value % 16 % 10);
        else
            ft_putchar('0' + value % 16);
    }
}

void    print_memory(const void *addr, size_t size)
{
    char    *ptr;
    size_t  i;

    if (addr && size > 0)
    {
        ptr = (char*)addr;
        i = 0;
        while (i < size)
        {
            print_hex(*(ptr + i), 0);
            if (i % 2)
                ft_putchar(' ');
            if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0 || (i + 1) == size)
                print_ascii(addr, i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works for your exam.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this... You said `printf()` is off limits, but you said nothing about sprintf.

```
 print_bytes(char *ptr, int count)
 {
   int i;
   char string[1024];
   string[0] = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
     sprintf(string,"%s %2x", string, *(ptr+i));
   }
   puts(string);
 }
```

This should loop through `count` bytes printing out each hexadecimal byte starting from the passed in address in `ptr`.

Obviously, this makes no attempt to properly size the string array.  That should be dynamically sized based on the passed in count.

To substitute `write()` for `puts()`, you could use:

```
 write(1, string, strlen(string)); /* 1 = STDOUT */
```

Comment: The OP explicitly said he can't use `printf()`

Comment: Revised to remove printf.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's a good way to do it. However would you be able to do it using only the 'write' function ?

Comment: Done.  If this satisfies, an upvote and accept would be appreciated. :)

Comment: @GautierLemaire: Why `write`? That's POSIX-specific. If you want portability, you should use something like `fputc` or `fputs`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Or `fwrite`, but this is obviously a homework assignment and the assignment might specify a POSIX machine.

Comment: Thank you again, but is there a way to get the adresse without using sprintf() ? As I said, the only function from the library I can use is write.

Comment: @DanielH: As the question already stated, and I failed to notice. Sorry about the noise. (My question still applies to the person who created the assignment, but not to the OP.)

Comment: @GautierLemaire: What address? If you're trying to do the equivalent of `printf("%p", ...)`, please state that in your question. That's the implication of what you've written, but it's contradicted by some of your comments. The "address of a pointer" could mean the address at which a pointer object is stored, but I think you want the *value* of the pointer.

Comment: I want to print the address at which the pointer is stored, using only the write function.

Comment: @GautierLemaire So if I have `char const *s = "Hello, world!"`, you want the equivalent of `printf("%p", &s);`? That is the address at which the pointer is stored. Or do you want the equivalent of `printf("%p", s);`? That is the address of the string, but the *value* of the pointer `s`.

Comment: @DanielH mmh, I have a serious doubt now, I'm still a beginner and I'm not used to precise vocabulary, I added the statement of my exercice in my question maybe it will be obvious for you